# Is version 2.1.2 compatible with React 15.5.4

Tags: react-select

Keep getting

show.self-a51f3f9200fc591428c13c03c87192475aa12504d581675df08c22f4a3799533.js?body=1:97366 Uncaught TypeError: custom is not a function

```
this.getStyles = function (key, props) {
    var base = _styles.defaultStyles[key](props);
    base.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    var custom = _this7.props.styles[key];
    return custom ? **custom(base, props)** : base;
  };
```

when trying to use react-select 2.1.2 with React 15.5.4, React-dom 15.5.4
(react-scripts not used)
Is it supposed to work?

Comment: You can check the live sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0x6q6v9o3v) but it seems to work well. 

The configuration I have used in the example is:

   `react 15.5.4
    react-dom 15.5.4
    react-scripts 1.0.0`

Can you edit you question to give more details ? Thanks

Comment: It looks like something got weird in our code causing the error, I was able to avoid the error now. It is not super clear how you replace old params: optionComponent and valueComponent with components.

Comment: did you figure it out ? I can send you an example of custom component

Comment: Not yet.

Stabs in the dark. I am trying to change the code from react-select 1 to 2 without knowing much about what's in optionComponent and valueComponent. Not sure what structure should look like with both of these in same select. You have plenty of samples showing a single component API usage. I need multiple usage sample. Specifically how to upgrade the V1 components.

Comment: You could create or update your question to add your v1 code so we can help you to switch it to v2..

Comment: I created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638863/how-to-upgrade-from-v1-to-v2-need-full-examples